# What decides whether query is nested or correlated?

Tags: database, subquery

I have gone through a number of resources to study `IN` and `Exists`, but still have a bit of confusion about what decides whether query works as correlated or not

If I add a statement like:

```
select * from emp where empno NOT IN (select mgr from emp)
```

It returns no data. However,

```
SELECT * FROM emp e1 where NOT EXISTS (select * from emp e2 where e1.empno=e2.mgr)
```

returns 8 rows of data.

I understand that the second one is a correlated query (for each row of outer query, inner query executes). My question is, what decides whether a query runs as nested or correlated?

Is it true that if inner query has a condition relating to outer table columns, then it will always act as a correlated query, irrespective of whether we use `IN` or `EXISTS`?

Comment: "for each row of outer query, [this] inner query executes" - this is not a universally true statement in context; a half-way decent query planner will treat it as a join.